# How to make maps marker title always visible for all showing places?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

i used marker.showInfoWindow(); it display one place title but i want display title all showing possible. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyvEZ.jpg)

public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        // map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

```
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);

    for(int i=0;i<arraylocation.size();i++) {
        String ab=arraylocation.get(i);
        StringTokenizer str=new StringTokenizer(ab,">>");
        String pic=str.nextToken();
        String a=str.nextToken();
        String b=str.nextToken();
        String Value3 = str.hasMoreTokens() ? str.nextToken() : null;
        String c=null;
        if(Value3 !=null && Value3.length()>0) {
            c = Value3;
        }else
        {
            c=" ";
        }

        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                R.drawable.lat);
        if(strLoc.contentEquals("1"))
        {
            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(pic);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                icon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(a), Double.parseDouble(b)), 16));
            marker=map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(getCircleBitmap(icon)))
                    .anchor(0.0f, 1.0f) // Anchors the marker on the bottom left
                    .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(a), Double.parseDouble(b))).title(c));
      marker.showInfoWindow();
        }else {


            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(a), Double.parseDouble(b)), 3));

 marker=  map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon))
                    .anchor(0.0f, 1.0f) // Anchors the marker on the bottom left
                    .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(a), Double.parseDouble(b))).title(c));
```

marker.showInfoWindow();
            }

Comment: Show the code around where you're displaying the info window.

Comment: above i put my code

Comment: It seems it is not possible to show multiple info windows at once.  This answer has a possible workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984118/show-info-window-on-every-marker-at-a-time