# Cloud with a title still on top

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have a lot markers with title, but i see this title only when I press on it. 
I would like to display their title immediately after the appearance on the map.
Is it possible ?

Comment: I think you can by creating a custom layout and replacing it with the default marker. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811579/how-to-create-a-custom-shaped-bitmap-marker-with-android-map-api-v2)

Comment: i want something like this -> showInfoWindow(); but this method show title only 1 marker, not all of my markers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [show info window on every marker at a time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984118/show-info-window-on-every-marker-at-a-time)