# How to show marker info for all markers at a time?

Tags: android, dictionary, marker

I am adding multiple markers on map. I am trying to show all markers info pannel when markers added on map, but able to show only last markers info. here is my code :

```
    /*Place all stores on map*/
private void placeMarkersOnMap() {
    for (int i = 0; i < store_list.size(); i++) {
        double latitude = Double.parseDouble(store_list.get(i).latitude.toString());
        double longitude = Double.parseDouble(store_list.get(i).longitude.toString());

        String title = store_list.get(i).id + " " + store_list.get(i).store_name.toString();
        String snipet = store_list.get(i).address + " ," + store_list.get(i).working_hours;

        Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                .title(title)
                .snippet(snipet).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(map_marker)));
        marker.showInfoWindow();
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 14));
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using Google map V2 ?

Comment: Looks not possible. for workaround see the accepted answer of this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984118/show-info-window-on-every-marker-at-a-time

Comment: @jiteshmohite yes I am using google map v2.

Comment: @PallaviTapkir have you solved these problem ?

Comment: @QadirHussain I have tried this solution but IconGenerator create icon as marker itself. I don't want that. I want to show title and snipet as info pannel to all markers and marker as well.

Comment: @jiteshmohite Not yet, working on that. Do you have any solution?

Comment: is @Qadir Hussain solution works for you. please have a look if you are not able to do please tell me

Comment: @jiteshmohite It works, but not as per my requirement. My requirement is for marker and infoWindow for both. Can you please post solution if you have?