# How to make info window of all pin visible by default in Xamarin Form googlemaps

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have rendered google map and pins in the map with googlemaps package in xamarin forms. I want to display title of all pins by default.
I tried

```
map.SelectedPin = pinname
```

but it works for only one pin. 
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984118/show-info-window-on-every-marker-at-a-time

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend the Map class, to create a Bindable list of Pins.

```
public class BindableMap : Map {
    public static readonly BindableProperty MapPinsProperty = BindableProperty.Create( 
             nameof(Pins), 
             typeof(ObservableCollection<Pin>),
             typeof(BindableMap), 
             new ObservableCollection<Pin>(),
             propertyChanged: (b, o, n) =>
             { 
                 var bindable = (BindableMap)b; 
                 bindable.Pins.Clear();

                 var collection = (ObservableCollection<Pin>)n; 
                 foreach (var item in collection) 
                     bindable.Pins.Add(item); 
                     collection.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) => 
                     { 
                         Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => 
                         { 
                             switch (e.Action) 
                             { 
                                 case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add: 
                                 case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace: 
                                 case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove: 
                                     if (e.OldItems != null) 
                                         foreach (var item in e.OldItems) 
                                             bindable.Pins.Remove((Pin)item);
                                     if (e.NewItems != null)
                                         foreach (var item in e.NewItems) 
                                             bindable.Pins.Add((Pin)item); 
                                     break;
                                 case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset: 
                                     bindable.Pins.Clear(); 
                                     break; 
                             } 
                         }); 
                     };
             });
    public IList<Pin> MapPins { get; set; }

}
```

Then, in your ViewModel

```
private ObservableCollection<Pin> _pinCollection = new ObservableCollection<Pin>(); 
public ObservableCollection<Pin> PinCollection { get { return _pinCollection; } set { _pinCollection = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
```

To add a simple pin:

```
PinCollection.Add(new Pin() { Position = YourPosition, Type = PinType.Generic, Label ="ABCD" });
```

You can now easily reference this control, with this XAML.

```
<local:BindableMap MapType="Street" MapPins="{Binding PinCollection}" />
```

Comment: This will not work, ShowInfoWindow on a marker will hide the info window on another other marker showing one.